# Create Typescript Macro

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use a wrapper around all my logs and I would like to know if there is a way to automaticly pass some variables if it exists on the scope.

Currently I am doing this :

```
function myLog(message: string, data: any): void {
   console.log(`Message Log : ${message}`);
   if (data !== undefined)
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function anyFunc(obj: any): void {
   myLog("new message", obj.info);
}

// prints :
// Message Log : new message
// {foo: true}
anyFunc({foo: "bar", info: {foo: true}});

// prints :
// Message Log : new message
anyFunc({foo: "bar"});
```

I would like to create some kind of Macro and automaticly pass `obj.info` if it exists

```
function MACRO (message: string) {
    myLog(message, (obj !== undefined ? obj.info : undefined));
}

function anyFunc(obj: any): void {
    MACRO("new message");
}
```

Is there any way I could acheive something like this ?

Thanks

Comment: Ther is a way to access the callee https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee but since it is not allowed in scrict mode and technicly depricated, no. You can take a look at decorators or mixins. They might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bellian, I have never used decorators and mixins so I have some trouble to find a way to use them. Could you show me a short example of what you have in mind ?